# “…that the privations on the soul grow ever more stark and ruinous by the day.” - Can the word “privations” be used in this format?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns, word-usage, sentence

Is it admissible to use to the phrase “privations on the soul” to describe the state in which the needs of the soul are not met and thus starved?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to show that you've looked up "privation" in a dictionary and what concerns you still have. If you want to focus on the word "on" (I would have expected "of"), please edit to clarify that.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to identify the source. Older English (Elizabethan?) sometimes used "on" where we would use "of"; see [definition 4 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on).